# Calling too many firebase function in one method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm currently making a method that allows current logged in user to sign up a new user and add them into as their downline friends using firebase. And while i was developing this method i realise that I've been bloating too much firebase functions into one method and i believe this would cause trouble when something is wrong with the inner function.

```
private void ValidateAccount(final String name, final String phone,final String email,
                                 final String password, final String confirmPassword,
                                 final String points,
                                 final DatabaseReference RootRef, final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            final FirebaseUser userkey = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            final String userkeyString = userkey.getUid();

                            RootRef.child(userkeyString)
                                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    if(!(dataSnapshot.exists())){
                                        HashMap<String, Object> userDatamap = new HashMap<>();
                                        final HashMap<String, Object> currentUserDatamap = new HashMap<>();
                                        userDatamap.put("id",userkeyString);
                                        userDatamap.put("phone",phone);
                                        userDatamap.put("name",name);
                                        userDatamap.put("email",email);

                                        userDatamap.put("upline", upline);

                                        addNewDownline(userkeyString);
                                        currentUserDatamap.put("downlines", downlinesMaps);

                                        RootRef.child(userkeyString).updateChildren(userDatamap)
                                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                        RootRef.child(currentUser.getId()).updateChildren(currentUserDatamap)
                                                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                                    @Override
                                                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                                                            Toast.makeText(RegisterDownlineActivity.this, "Congratulations your account has been created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                                                                            firebaseAuth.signOut();
                                                                            Intent intent =  new Intent(RegisterDownlineActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                                                            startActivity(intent);
                                                                        }
                                                                        else{
                                                                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                                                                            Toast.makeText(RegisterDownlineActivity.this, "Network Error: Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                                Toast.makeText(RegisterDownlineActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                            }
                                                        });

                                                    }
                                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                Toast.makeText(RegisterDownlineActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        });

                                    }
                                    else{
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterDownlineActivity.this,"The username already belong to someone else.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterDownlineActivity.this, "Please try again using another username.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        Intent intent =  new Intent(RegisterDownlineActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterDownlineActivity.this, "System Error. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else{
                            Log.d( "FAIL", String.valueOf(task.getException()));
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterDownlineActivity.this, "Authentication failed."+String.valueOf(task.getResult()),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                try{
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterDownlineActivity.this, "Authentication failed: Email is already being used",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                }
                catch (RuntimeExecutionException task){
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterDownlineActivity.this, "Authentication failed: Email is already being used",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

For example, if something is wrong with the `updateChildren()` then the method will show failure at the `updateChildren()` part, but the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` will still execute.

What i wish to achieve is that whenever there's an error in the function all the function will not execute and shows the error.

Comment: function will execute but in your hand to use or not response data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` executed and `updateChildren()` failed, then inside `.addOnFailureListener` you can delete the user:

```
.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
   @Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
  FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
  user.delete();
  Toast.makeText(RegisterDownlineActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: What about the nested `updateChildren()`? say... `RootRef.child(userkeyString).updateChildren(userDatamap)` works but `RootRef.child(currentUser.getId()).updateChildren(currentUserDatamap)` fails

Comment: its after the hashmap declaration

Comment: why do you have two `updateChildren()` after each other?

Comment: I'm updating 2 databases

Comment: okay in the end you need to handle it in `addOnFailureListener`  if one of them fails just delete the data that was added